# Not even a error nor the program is running in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Hello every one I trying to build a basic program of finding the area and perimeter of a triangle. I am pretty new to eclipse. The compiler doesn't run or show errors for this program but runs the program which was previously run. The code of my program is :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solution 
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        double b,h,o,t;
        System.out.println("Enter the length of base");
        b=input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the length of heigth");
        h=input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the length of sideOne");
        o=input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the length of sideTwo");
        t=input.nextDouble();
        input.close();

        Attributes Val= new Attributes();
        Val.setbase(b);
        Val.setheight(h);
        Val.setsideOne(o);
        Val.setsideTwo(t);

        double result=Val.area();
        System.out.println("the area of triangle is:"+result);
        result=Val.peri();
        System.out.println("the perimeter of triangle is:"+result);

    }
}
```

The other class is

```
public class Attributes 
{
    private double base,height,sideOne,sideTwo;

    public double area()
    {
        double area=this.base*this.height/2;
        return area;
    }

    public double peri()
    {
        double peri=base+sideOne+sideTwo;
        return peri;
    }

    public double getbase()
    {
        return this.base;
    }
    public double getheight()
    {
        return this.height;
    }
    public double getsideOne()
    {
        return this.sideOne;
    }
    public double getsideTwo()
    {
        return this.sideTwo;
    }
    public void setbase(double base)
    {
        this.base=base;
    }
    public void setheight(double height)
    {
        this.height=height;
    }
    public void setsideOne(double sideOne)
    {
        this.sideOne=sideOne;
    }
    public void setsideTwo(double sideTwo)
    {
        this.sideTwo=sideTwo;
    }
}
```

Could you help me with the issue and suggest me if any errors are present in the program.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Not really a comment on the code, but if you're taking the three side lengths, you don't need the height to find the area. [Heron's Formula](http://www.mathopenref.com/heronsformula.html)

Comment: Well ya I do know the formula. But i was given specific variables and method names for practice. I am a beginner and I learning to code so i followed that problem statement and then written my code. Even other issues also arise like concept of sum of two sides must be greater than other side, but those were of least priority to me when i learning how to code. And ya, i have to improve the habit of adding comments to the code. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not declared the `main` method properly. As execution of program starts from the `main` method, make sure you are running the class which contains proper declaration of a `main` method.

Your main method should be like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Starting point of application
}
```

See for instance the [wiki at c2.com](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PublicStaticVoidMain) for more information.

Comment: Dude thanks alot, I was scratching my head from an hour. It's time for me to get good at basics.